# What’s a semi-formal American equivalent for the British expression “value for money”?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, idiom-requests, transatlantic-differences, proverb-requests

I'm searching for an American phrase that would be equivalent to the British *“X is great value for money”*, one that’s not too colloquial and can be used in a serious product description.

I am aware of following phrases with my objection in parentheses.

1. price-performance ratio (not frequently used)
2. cost-benefit ratio (not the same)
3. Bang for your buck (too colloquial)
4. A great buy (too colloquial)
5. bargain at twice the price (too colloquial)

The British version is neutral and can be used in a formal product description of a technical product for marketing purposes.

It may be the case that #1 is the best or only choice, but I wanted to canvas for other ideas.

Comment: Actually, the "BE" phrase you quote is perfectly fine for AE usage, where more formality is required than "bang for the buck". Less formal is an emphasized "worth the price", e.g., "unquestionably worth the price". You might also hear "get what you pay for", but I'd class this as at least as inappropriately colloquial as your #4 or #5.

Comment: I've never seen it used in AE texts and "for money" without a definite article is very odd and definitely British. Perhaps "great value for your money" is better

Comment: @SonOfPingu Or *a great value for the money*. I agree you need some determiner in there in the US. Also, *a great value at the price*. The latter shows up frequently in online reviews. As such, it might be a bit colloquial, but I think these reviewers are trying to sound formal and serious.

Comment: What's wrong with simply *value*? *Trading at a forward PE of only 6, ABC Corp presents a great value* or *The beef at Try'n'Save is cheaper per pound, but has a lot of fat and bone; the beef at Buy'n'Large is the better value.*

Comment: @choster While technically meaning the same as just value alone, ideally it emphasizes that the performance/benefit for that price represents great value. So product X may be the best overall but costs more. Product Y  gives you the best performance in relation to its price.

Comment: The expression is the same in AmE. Where did you get the idea it wasn't?? But in both: X is a great value for **your** or for **the** money. There is no British version. That is false.

Comment: @Lambie - I've seen it listed as BE in several dictionaries not to mention its frequency in organic Google results in the UK, but not US. What is the source for your position?

Comment: @SonOfPingu Well, dictionaries can be crap, fyi. My source is my head and the fact that I wrote features for British and American business publications. How's that? :)

Comment: I have heard “good value for money” in New York in conversation with native-born Americans. I don’t think it’s a specifically British usage.

Comment: I think Jeff Zeitlin is wholly correct. Although I don’t often talk to US Americans as such, I do think it would be hard to find one who did follow even one or two of your examples but didn’t understand ‘Value for money’ even if he’d never heard the phrase before.
Please, SonOfPingu, why do you think  ‘Value for money’ - or any similar phrase - is not self explanatory?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin - I never said it wasn't self-explanatory. There's plenty of BE phrases an AE speaker can understand and/or guess. But that was not the point of my question. I specifically asked for an AE phrase.

Comment: OK… then try talking to more speakers, or reading more writers or American English and when you can explain why more than two or three of them think there's any kind of problem, please post the details they gave you.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I think you're right and the asker wrong, since  according to Google Books, the phrase is [even more common in American books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=value+for+money&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvalue%20for%20money%3B%2Cc0) than in [British ones](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=value+for+money&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvalue%20for%20money%3B%2Cc0).  This request appears to be based on a false premise, or at best on an unproven one.

Comment: Yes and how is *X is great value for money* too colloquial? Why should it no be used in your serious product description?

Comment: @tchrist It’s about eight times more common in British books than in American ones going by the Ngrams you linked to. Did you miss that there are four leading zeroes in the AmE resutls, but only three in the BrE ones? I’d have to agree that the phrase is more common in BrE than AmE, though it exists and sounds perfectly natural eitherwhere. (And the Ngrams both agree that the versions with _the_ or _your_ are far rarer.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I missed a zero. Still, I think it's perfectly normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion and examples given, "X is great value for your money" (using definite articles in AE) is acceptable and common AE. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I've heard the phrase "get(ting) your money's worth" to say that the cost is proportional to the value you received. It is used as a positive expression for expensive items rather than having the same negative connotation as "you get what you pay for" commonly used with inexpensive and low quality items.